# Critical Windows 7 system files?

Tags: windows-7

Which Windows 7 file(s) are critical for booting?

In other words, what is the shortest way to irreversibly dismantle a Windows 7 instance via a batch script, assuming we have root privileges?

I googled a bit, but I found ambiguous information.

*I'm asking this out of curiousity - not to do evil deeds.

Comment: Try [SU] for questions about operating systems and other general computing; Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about booting files is that all of them can easily be restored.  If you want to irreveribly degrade Windows about the only thing you can do is destroy the registry files.  See this link for the location of the registry archives.

http://www.easydesksoftware.com/regfiles.htm